# integer constant is too large for "long" type

Tags: c, random

I am creating random integers with the following algorithm:

```
int random;

int i;
for (i = 0; i < RANDOM_COUNT; i++) {
    random = (((int) rand() << 0) & 0x0000FFFFd)
            | (((int) rand() << 16) & 0xFFFF0000d);
    fprintf(outputFile, " %d\n", random);
}
```

I am getting the following warning:

`warning: integer constant is too large for "long" type`

on this line:

`| (((int) rand() << 16) & 0xFFFF0000d);`

I am using GCC 3.4.3 to compile the code.

Does anyone know which part of the operation is triggering the warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does anyone know which part of the operation [`(((int) rand() << 16) & 0xFFFF0000d);`] is triggering the warning?

Yes, it's the `0xFFFF0000d`, because it's 36 bits in size. Note that this number is equal to `0xFFFF0000D`. You probably meant `0xFFFF0000`.

Likewise, `0x0000FFFFd` is equal to `0x0000FFFFD`. You probably meant `0x0000FFFF`.